# Using Drupal Language Switcher Causes CiviCRM to Fail on Membership Registration Page

Tags: drupal, multilingual

We have a membership page that can be accessed in either Spanish or English. If you go to the English or Spanish page with its direct URL the page works as expected.  It even works if you use the CiviCRM [Language Switcher](https://civicrm.org/blog/ayduns/language-switcher) extension to switch languages. However, if you use the Drupal Language Switcher than it does not work.

We get:
"CRM_Core_Exception: We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.
Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.
Error type: Could not find a valid session key. in /var/www/networkpaao/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Controller.php on line 881"

There are no additional errors in the Drupal logs or in the ConfigAndLog log for CiivCRM.

I have checked the cookies in the Developer console and there is a cookie being set by Drupal. I am not using any tools for changing my cookies.  I can get this error logged on or not. I can get this error in multiple browsers on multiple computers.

I have also tested that other pages with CiviCRM content work correctly when using the Drupal Language Switcher. For example, our registration page.

We have CiviCRM 5.57.1 and Drupal 9.4.3.

I am not sure when this problem started but it has worked in the past.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!